# Single Sign-on from mvc app using adfs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, adfs

I have a project i built using MVC, i want to able to access the application via adfs authentication, i have read a couple of stuffs on how to achieve this but no joy yet! this was my implementation:

i generated machine using iis machine key tool, add the following line of codes to the config file:

```
<machineKey validationKey ="93D05346B46FD7BBB26002D0ADE91869729F11883668BFB65DB32449
A5DC880B709F7377EDD4FC47178EFF11F59A578605BFD93C077" 
decryptionKey="6ECD77045F376D9763D74B4D3DC64FE33D1E231D" 
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" /> 
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 <authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="https://fs.removed.com.ng/adfs/ls/" 
defaultUrl="http://removed/" slidingExpiration="false" 
timeout="12000" requireSSL="true" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

having this error:

```
•Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-b5cc-0480020000eb
•Error time: Tue, 28 Nov 2017 16:33:28 GMT
•Cookie: enabled
•User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.3; 
WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 
2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0)
```

and this was the url while trying to access the application:

```
https://Removed/adfs/ls/?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

i will appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an application (the RP) that connects up with ADFS with a supported protocol (via “Add Relying Party Trust”).

If you have ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) you could use [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs) or for earlier versions, you could use [WIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/building-my-first-claims-aware-aspnet-web-app).

Comment: yes i have added Relying party trust to the ADFS, yet no luck

Comment: Have a look at the code samples in the links. You don't need to do anything with machine key.

Comment: There is no Application group under ADFS manager, i only have Service, Trust Relationships and Authentication policies

Comment: You should have Claims Providers and Relying Parties? What version of ADFS?

Comment: I am using ADFS 2.0

Comment: Hence no application group. There is no OAuth support in ADFS 2.0. Use WIF as per link above.

Comment: Please do i need to create a relying party trust if i am to follow the above link using WIF?

Comment: Yes - all applications need a RP.

Comment: Sorry sir for my plenty questions, i still want to ask one more question: i was following a tutorial i found on this link: http://www.cloudriven.fi/en/cloud-9-en/how-to-implement-sso-for-asp-net-mvc-application-with-adfs/, but the writer didn't specify where to place the C# code in the application, i will appreciate if you could help out here. Thanks a million.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/security/how-to-build-claims-aware-aspnet-mvc-web-app-using-wif This will display the claims. Normally added to a controller.

Comment: Please is this where i should specify the url to the ADFS: issuer="http://localhost:13922/wsFederationSTS/Issue" ?

Comment: Follow the format here : https://gist.github.com/nzpcmad/050933a3144b0e8f068d4f948387278a

Comment: Thanks for the link above, that looks like it, but please i still have need for clarifications, i want users to be redirected to my application after being authenticated with adfs. Also where do i going to get this xml file from: initializeData="C:\Logs\ClassicASPWIF.xml" Thanks

Comment: The "allow" / "deny" at the top of the gist forces authentication on any page so accessing any page will redirect to ADFS. That is just an output log file. Point it to anywhere you want

Comment: Thank you sir, It's working now only that when user is redirected to the application, he is being prompted with a windows login screen, i don't think this second authentication is necessary after being authenticated on ADFS. I have commented this line of code : <deny users="?" /> and the authentication mode is set to None, but the issue still persist. I will appreciate if you could assist further. Thanks

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?  Is this perhaps an IIS issue?

Comment: I have been able to resolve the second authentication window issue, thanks for the guide. now, i want to be able to call and use: FederationMetadataLocation key in the application, i know i need this to authenticate users and also how to get ThumpPrint from ADFS. Thanks

Comment: Thumbprint - view the details of the certificate under the Certificate tab in ADFS.

Comment: Thanks sir, i have been able to get the ThumbPrint, what i said about the Metadata was that: I have added a key in the AppSettings section of the web.config file: <add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://fs.9mobile.com.ng/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />, is there a way to use this key in the application?

Comment: WIF uses it automatically.